# React page shows the content and then shuts down after one second on node.js only

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am learning React, one of the examples I am practicing is getting data from Reddit api.

I have tried this code on "codesandbox" and it is working fine. But with node js it shows the first line "/r/reactjs" only and then turns off. It doesn't even show the data from Reddit inside the rendered page however when I checked React developer tools, the state has the array from Reddit api, so it is there already.

Here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';

class Reddit extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json`)
    .then(res => {
      const posts = res.data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
      this.setState({ posts });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
  });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='reddit_data'>
        <h1>/r/reactjs</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post => {
            return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Reddit />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: How did you set up your NodeJS project? Did you export your code from CodeSandBox to your local machine?

Comment: I doubt there is any issue related to using Node here. I think the error is in your React code. Can you please try console logging the complete error object in your catch method and let us know what you get?

Comment: No I didn't export it. I use elementary os that is based on Ubuntu. So I installed it through terminal and run the project with "npm start"

Comment: Here are problems from console 
- "Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."
- "Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Comment: I seem to have **no** trouble with your `Reddit` component. https://i.imgur.com/0sYq3ro.png.  I copied your source into CodeSandBox (https://codesandbox.io/s/311jzxyl81), exported it to GitHub (https://github.com/dance2die/so.answer.51577212) and the cloned it, `git clone https://github.com/dance2die/so.answer.51577212`. Lastly, I ran `npm i` and `npm run`.

That's why I asked how your set up your NodeJS project in the comment above.

Comment: I have no problem running it on codesandbox also.
Should I re-install NodeJs ?

Comment: Would you share your SandBox link? & what version of node & npm version you have? You can check by running `node --version` and also `npm --version`.  I am using `node -> v9.9.0` & `npm -> 5.6.0`.

Comment: oh, node version is v4.2.6 and npm version is 3.5.2.
I just installed Node and npm yesterday, why is it not the last version as I installed it through termial

Comment: They are very old versions. Yes, try to update your node & npm versions

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will answer the question as it may help someone else.

Comment: Make sure you have `node version >= 6`: reference -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I have older version of NodeJS and NPM.

Make sure you have node version >= 6: reference -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the confirmation 

Comment: _shameless plug_ I kinda knew that the node version was old because of -> https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/89  